# Converter arquivo .log para .txt em Bash

Tags: linux, bash, docker, log, txt

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso converter um arquivo .log gerado em um container no Docker e converter ele para um arquivo txt usando Bash.

Comment: Que tipo de arquivo é esse .log gerado pelo Docker, por acaso ja é um arquivo texto? Consegue abri-lo com o vi por exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se ajudaria mas você pode usar o comando de mover do Unix.

Exemplos

`mv MeuArquivo.log MeuArquivo.txt`

Ou em um diretório específico...

`mv /var/logs/MeuArquivo.log /var/logs/MeuArquivo.txt`